# Kruskals Algorithm - Sort an adjacency matrix in ascending order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, matrix

So I am using an adjacency matrix for my kruskals algorithm implementation, but I was unsure how I would go about sorting this matrix.

while still remembering which two vertices that weighted edge belongs to. I was thinking of iterating over the matrix and adding the lowest weight edge to a new matrix and continuing this process until all the values are in ascending order and added to that new matrix.

However I then end up not knowing which two vertices those edge values belonged to. So I wanted to ask how I would possibly go about ordering my values in ascending order, while remembering which row and column each value belongs to.

Is there a specific way of doing this? Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: create a class `Edge` which represents an edge and stores the weight, the source and the destination of the the edge. Compare `Edge` elements by their weight

Comment: Kruskal with an adjacency matrix isn't a great choice -- Prim with a trivial priority queue is only O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to sort the matrix as is - use an alternative container with reference to the matrix cell to store the edges and sort them. An example structure for this would look something like:

```
class Edge implements Comparable {
  int weight;
  int i; // x coordinate in the matrix
  int j; // y coordinate in the matrix
  int compareTo(Edge rhs) {
    return weight - rhs.weight;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall try this :)